# Pressing a button sets another to be shown as active

Tags: html

I have a button that has 2 different colors. I don't know about a way to color a button with 2 colors and I want to avoid from putting an image to be the background so I guess that I need 2 buttons (one under the other).
Both of the colors have to be changed when pressed (active).
Does anybody knows a way to make another button to be shown as active when the first one is pressed?

Comment: You want this? http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ On `:active` just set other colors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[playground](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)***

```
<button>BUTTON</button>
```

```
button{
  padding:10px 25px;
  color:#fff;
  border:0;
  background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #207cca 48%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(48%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 48%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 48%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 48%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 48%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
button:active{
 background: #b4ddb4; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b4ddb4 0%, #70aa7d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b4ddb4), color-stop(100%,#70aa7d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b4ddb4 0%,#70aa7d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b4ddb4 0%,#70aa7d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b4ddb4 0%,#70aa7d 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b4ddb4 0%,#70aa7d 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b4ddb4', endColorstr='#70aa7d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:active` psudeo class:

```
input
{
    color:red;
}

input:active
{
    color:blue;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KGcEq/1/)